# How to put Google Maps in TableView - Swift 3

Tags: ios, uitableview, google-maps, swift3

I'm new to Swift Programming. I'm trying to put Google Map in `UITableView`. Can I do that?

The User Interface should be like this:

[image]

Here is my code for implementing UITableView using Storyboard:

```
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 3
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        var rowCount = 0

        if section == 0 {
            rowCount = 1
        }

        if section == 1 {
            rowCount = arrayOfStatic.count
        }
        if section == 2 {
            rowCount = arrayOfDynamic.count
        }

        return rowCount
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            return 250
        } else {
            return 70
        }
    }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "mapsCellId", for: indexPath) as! GoogleMapsCell
        return cell
    } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "staticCellId", for: indexPath) as! StaticCell
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "placesCellId", for: indexPath) as! PlacesCell
        let ip = indexPath

        cell.imageFoursquarePlaces.image = arrayOfDynamic[indexPath.row].image
        cell.labelPlacesName.text = arrayOfDynamic[ip.row].name
        cell.labelPlacesCategory.text = arrayOfDynamic[ip.row].category
        return cell
    }
}
```

Here is my code for implementing `UITableViewCell` in the first section of `UITableView`:

```
class GoogleMapsCell: UITableViewCell, GMSMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var googleMapsView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonCurrentLoc: UIButton!

    var googleMaps: GMSMapView!
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var camera = GMSCameraPosition()

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        self.showCurrentLocationOnMap()
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func showCurrentLocationOnMap() {

        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: (self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude)!, zoom: 15)
        self.googleMaps = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0, width: self.googleMapsView.frame.size.width, height: self.googleMapsView.frame.height), camera: camera)

        do {
            if let styleURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "style", withExtension: "json") {
                self.googleMaps.mapStyle = try GMSMapStyle(contentsOfFileURL: styleURL)
            } else {
                NSLog("Unable to find style.json")
            }
        } catch {
            NSLog("The style definition could not be loaded: \(error)")
        }
        self.googleMaps.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        self.googleMaps.accessibilityElementsHidden = false

        self.addSubview(self.googleMaps)
        self.googleMaps.camera = camera
        self.addSubview(self.buttonCurrentLoc)
    }

}
```

It gives me result:

[image]

I have a `searchBar` as `HeaderView`. I tried to put Google Map View by creating a `UIView` inside the first cell of TableView. But I can't show the Google Map View and the button can't be clicked. How can I do that?

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: are you setting up desired delegates in cell?

Comment: @SyedAliSalman, I've implemented `GMSMapViewDelegate` and `CLLocationManagerDelegate` for `GoogleMapsCell` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to call `showCurrentLocationOnMap` method with your `GoogleMapsCell`'s instance in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "mapsCellId", for: indexPath) as! GoogleMapsCell

//add this method call
cell.showCurrentLocationOnMap()

return cell
```

Or you can override `awakeFromNib` in your `GoogleMapsCell` and call the `showCurrentLocationOnMap` method with it.

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.showCurrentLocationOnMap()
}
```

Comment: oh, yes! i forgot to write that part. Thanks!

Comment: @user1994 Welcome mate :)

Comment: Although I use Apple Maps, this has been extremely helpful in pointing me in the right direction.  I tried doing everything in the TableViewController, but you've shown that it should be the TableViewCell that should actually be doing all the work... The TableViewController should just provide the data (CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates).Thank you very much for this!